# Azure AD B2C Api Connector for Sign In for external authentication

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We have on-prem sql server database which is connected to a legacy application. The on-prem database contains the username and password for the users. We are in process of migrating the existing solution to Cloud, and using Azure AD B2C for Authentication.

As the existing system is very big, so there is a phased transition we need to do which means keeping the both system running, allowing the users to login to the existing app as well as through Azure AD B2C in the cloud app.

I stumbled across API connectors for Azure AD B2C. I want to know if its possible to implement API connector for Sign In flow, in a way that it does the authentication against the external database store (legacy database) instead of Azure AD B2C.

From whatever I researched on google, it seems that API connector is called after authentication only. Also all the samples were related to Sign up flow. Can someone please guide me for a sample to achieve the login through external database using API connector ?

Answer (score 1):

B2C supports integrating external identity providers. You can find a full list of them here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-local?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

However, you are seeking to use a custom (generic) identity provider (IDP). This scenario is supported if the custom IDP supports either the OpenID Connector (OIDC) or SAML protocols. Please check that list in the URL above to review these options.

Regarding using the API connector, you can invoke the API connector before the authentication occurs in B2C using a [validation technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/validation-technical-profile) in a custom policy. However, that does not achieve the actual authentication based on OIDC. Instead, it would be considered a validation step.

An overview of when you can use API Connectors is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/api-connectors-overview?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

You might be able to achieve a type of workaround using a custom policy to invoke your API connector to authenticate before authenticating in B2C and returning a success flag.

However, I think a better idea is to implement password synchronization. This seems like a perfect fit for you based on what you described. Users would be able to log into both your local system and Azure B2C simultaneously until you decommission your legacy authentication mechanism.

Your main requirement is that you have use a Microsoft Graph API SDK to update the B2C account password via your application backend. The bottom line is that you just need to keep the passwords the same in both systems. This is very easy to achieve with the Graph API, especially if you are developing in C# / .NET.

You also have to figure out how the B2C accounts get provisioned in the first place. This can happen in several different ways depending on your business requirements: Graph API, user sign up flow, import operation, etc.

Answer (score 0):

API connectors only work for sign-up.

There's an example [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/using-a-different-identity-repository-for-authentication-using-azure-ad-b2c-e662bf17e072) but you will have to use custom policies.